# Fogbugz -- expanded case list?

Tags: fogbugz

I'm having trouble reading the list of cases in Fogbugz; is there a way to make it show the entire text of each case individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **Mouse Over** the **Case** column hyperlink for each case, there is a very detailed popup dialog which includes details of the last comment/update to the case.

I think the Fogbugz list by design does not show full text each case, only part of the first line of the last comment/update to the case.

By the way there is a StackExchange site for Fogbugz - http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/
probably you may check out if you can get other response there...